# Email in batch class

Tags: apex, email, batch

I am able to send email in batch class.But email is being send to Gmail only.It is not getting send to other type of email like company email. Execute method is working fine for other type mail but email is not getting send. Anyone has any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Batch will not check anything related to Email. You can send Email to any email from Batch. It could be because of Below reason

- Your Code could have condition
- Your company have some security
- Your Org could have some security to send Email